# Multi dimensional array value assignment in verilog

Tags: verilog

The verilog below code as you see uses a multi-dimensional register array for storing the data.

```
parameter DSIZE = 8;
parameter ASIZE = 4;

input [DSIZE-1:0] wdata;
input wclk,wen;

reg [ASIZE:0] wptr;

parameter MEMDEPTH = 1<<ASIZE;
reg [DSIZE-1:0] ex_mem [0:MEMDEPTH-1];

always @(posedge wclk)
  if (wen)
    ex_mem[wptr[ASIZE-1:0]] <= wdata;
```

I do not properly understand what happens in the last assignment statement in which `ex_mem` is assigned the value in `wdata`. What does the part in the brackets (`wptr[ASIZE-1:0]`) associated with `ex_mem` return and to what location of `ex_mem` does `wdata` get stored into?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are not  understanding. `wptr[ASIZE-1:0]` evaluates to the `ASIZE` lowest bits of `wptr`, and when interpreted as a location in `ex_mem`, well, `wdata` gets stored into that location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code, `ex_mem` is a memory that has 16 (`MEMDEPTH`) slots. Each slot has 8 (`DSIZE`) bits. 16 slots can be addressed by 4 (`ASIZE`) bits, but `wptr` is a 5-bit signal for some reason, so its most significant bit (MSB) is not used for addressing the memory.

```
ex_mem[wptr[ASIZE-1:0]] <= wdata;
```

Since `wptr[ASIZE-1:0]` is a 4-bit signal (for `ASIZE=4`), the assignment above may write to a slot between `ex_mem[0]` and `ex_mem[15]`.

Answer (score 1):

'wptr' is just a one-dimensional register.

So, first of all verilog extracts an index to ex_mem from the 'wptr' thing. It uses this range to do so: ASIZE-1:0.

If ASIZE is 4, as in your example, it can sample values from 0 to 15 from there. For example,

```
 reg [4:0] wptr = 0x1B;
 wptr[3:0] will give you 'B' (11).
```

Now this index value will be applied to the ex_mem array to write your data.